# Double cover the edges of a complete graph by smaller complete graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we have a complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices. Are there any results on the ways to cover $K_n$ with $k$ copies of $K_m$, for $m<n$, such that each edge of $K_n$ is contained in exactly two of the copies of $K_m$? I've been able to find results on [clique covering](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254012/cover-a-complete-graph-by-smaller-complete-graphs) and [the cycle double cover problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065766/cycle-double-cover-conjecture-for-complete-graphs) for complete graphs, but nothing on double covering by complete graphs in particular.

It may be of note that this is exactly the cycle double cover problem for $n=4$ (in which case $m$ must be $3$, and $K_3$ is a cycle), but this falls apart once $m\geq 4$. Links to resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: This problem has a more set-combinatorial description which may be easier to find results on - you are seeking a collection of $k$ $m$-element subsets of $[n]$ such that each pair of elements is contained in exactly two of these elements. I'm afraid I cannot comment on what results there are known about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a design theory question.  You are asking about the existence of a [Balanced Incomplete Block Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) (BIBD).  A *$(v,k,t,\lambda)$-design* is a collection of $k$-subsets (called *blocks*) of a $v$-element set $X$ such that every $t$-subset of $X$ is contained in exactly $\lambda$ blocks.  You are interested in the case $t=\lambda=2$.  There are some obvious divisibility conditions.  For example, $\binom{k}{2}$ must divide $\lambda \binom{v}{2}$.  Moreover, the condition on pairs also implies that the number of blocks containing a single element is also constant.  So, $k-1$ must also divide $\lambda (v-1)$. It was a famous open problem called the *Existence Conjecture*, whether these divisibility conditions were also sufficent (up to a finite number of counterexamples).  In a series of influential papers in the 1970s, Richard Wilson solved the Existence Conjecture for $t=2$.  Recently, Peter Keevash solved the Existence Conjecture in general.  See the paper [The existence of designs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3665) and the references therein.